# How to set Admob appID programmatically (19.1.0)?

Tags: android, admob

Before [version 19.1.0](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/rel-notes), the appID could be set programmatically like this:

```
MobileAds.initialize (Context context, String appID)
```

The new method is

```
initialize(Context, OnInitializationCompleteListener)
```

Internally, that method passes `null` as appID:

```
public static void initialize(Context var0, OnInitializationCompleteListener var1) {
    zzxw.zzqq().zza(var0, (String)null, var1);
}
```

Does this mean that appID should no longer be set programmatically?

Answer (score 4):

You have to put APPLICATION_ID on manifest file , you can find your App ID in the AdMob UI. For android:value insert your own AdMob App ID in quotes, as shown below.

```
<manifest>
<application>
    <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
</application>
```

after that you can change it programmatically

```
 try {
        ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
        String myApiKey = bundle.getString("com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID");
        Log.d(TAG, "Name Found: " + myApiKey);
        ai.metaData.putString("com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID", "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");//you can replace your key APPLICATION_ID here
        String ApiKey = bundle.getString("com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID");
        Log.d(TAG, "ReNamed Found: " + ApiKey);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load meta-data, NameNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load meta-data, NullPointer: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: This does not update the actual value. If I run the same method again, it shows the old value.

Comment: how can we be sure that Admob actually used new value?

Comment: I dont know who are those guys give this answer up vote without validating it . Just repeat first four lines after the last line of try catch block,you will get same value with no chnage .This answer is totally miss leading .

Comment: Is this really workaround? Is it possible to change app id? If yes why the answer is not approved?

Comment: Actual value of `APP ID` is not changed.

Comment: Downvoted since this is not a working solution as others have commented.

Comment: What If we have two ads like interstitial and banner ad, Then how to add these two app_id inside the manifest file. Can we have two <meta-data with ```com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID```

Answer (score -3):

You just need to set the app-id in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and the same will be picked up by the SDK automatically.

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="
```

Refer: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: i dont want to put it manifest because i want change it from server dynamically. do you know any solution?

Comment: have you found any solution?