# Change android manifest meta-data programatically in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-manifest

I'm in a situation where I could really use functionality to change meta-data in manifest at run-time in my Flutter app. As per my understanding, the androidmanifest.xml elements are only set at compile-time. While trying to find some solution, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63639174/5209982) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54732632/5209982) which says otherwise.

Now I'm curious to know if it is really possible to update these meta-data(s) at runtime? If yes then how to implement this functionality on Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, updating meta-data is possible in Android, but it's limited to some tags.

About modifying them via Flutter, just like any other platform-specific API, you should use channels:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

It looks complex but easy to use. Check the battery level reading sample above, it's quite clear.

Comment: Thank you for answering this. I hope it works for my usecase i.e. updating AdMob ID(similar to first hyper-linked example).