# get Admob AppId programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin, admob

How can I get the AppId that is used by admob. in fact I want to change admob AppId programmatically using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63639174/13083841) answer. but I'm not able to verify that Admob is actually using new value.